# how to expand/collapse and add new lines to a div on clicking in a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have some divs and when clicking on the button Expand/collapse i need a function that allows my client to add more divs on the form or not, like on the picture attached[image]

i have tried the follwing code, its not working when clicking on the button, nothing happens

```
<div class="divVisible" id="mytable">
<p><label class="field2">Centro de Custo:</label><input type="text" class="text" id="centroCusto" name="centroCusto"></p>
<p><label class="field">Conta Contabil:</label><input type="text" class="text" id="contaContabil" name="contaContabil"/></p>
<p><label class="field">Periodo:</label><input type="text" class="num" id="date" name="date"/></p>
<p><label class="field">Saldo:</label><input type="text" class="num" id="saldo" name="saldo"/></p>
<p><label class="field">Saldo Total:</label><input type="text" class="num" id="saldoTotal" name="saldoTotal"/></p>
</div>
<input id="show_hide" type="button" value="Collapse/Expand" />
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#show_hide").click(function() {
$("#mytable").append('<p><label class="field">Saldo:</label><input type="text" class="num" id="saldo" name="saldo"/></p>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: It is working well: http://jsfiddle.net/vXdtg/ are you sure you did include jQuery library?

Comment: @Alvaro and how can i collapse if i mistaken expand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you append the HTML you will just be creating a new element each time you click. You could always just have the HTML on the page with `display:none`, and then use jQuery `.toggle()` or `.slideToggle()` to expand/collapse.